# withtype fails with mlton and succeeds with smlnj

Tags: types, recursion, sml, smlnj

I am writing an application where I want to define many types in the withtype clause of a datatype declaration. The following code snippet demonstrates it:

```
datatype ta = A
withtype tb = int
     and tc = tb
```

**mlton** fails to compile this code, although **smlnj** succeeds.

```
$ mlton -stop o test.sml
Error: test.sml 3.15.
  Undefined type tb.
compilation aborted: parseAndElaborate reported errors
```

I am using mlton-20100608 and smlnj-110.71.

Is this a bug in mlton?

I do not know how to proceed without this sort of declaration: a set of mutually recursive datatypes and types.

The idea comes from the abstract syntax tree types proposed by Andrew Appel for the Tiger language in his book [*Modern Compiler Implementation in ML*](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/ml/), page 98, in file [`absyn.sml`](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/ml/chap4/absyn.sml)

Answer (score 1):

According to Andreas Rossberg from the mlton community, this is not a bug with mlton, but a (known) deviation from the standard on SML/NJ's part. According to the spec, the type abbreviations following `withtype` are **not** recursive with each other, only with the preceding datatypes. The example gets rewritten to

```
datatype ta = A
type tb = int
and tc = tb
```

That is, MLton is correct to flag this.

One can always expand out the the other type constructors on the right-hand sides, so it's no real limitation. Having to do so can be quite a nuisance, though.